# css apply color to div id and class

Tags: html, css

When i apply color to div  id and class it does not works. Please provide solution for this .I am trying to add color for div   in the following code:
html:

```
body { 
    background-color:#666 
}
.header{
  padding: 10px;
  /*float:left; */
  margin-left:auto;
  width:100%; 
  background-color:#C60;
  height:60px; 
  /*position:fixed; width:100%; */
  overflow:hidden
}    

.logo1 { 
  /**width:14%;
  /height: 70px;
  /*margin-left: 20px; 
  /float: left; */
  color : #0F0;
  overflow : auto 
}
```

Here  tag color is not working properly.

HTML :

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper" >
    <div class="header">    
       <div class="logo1"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML and a working Fiddle or Codepen.

Comment: background-color : #0F0;  instead of color do you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/fwkWG/506/

Comment: @user  is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31783797/4323504 what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `color` property will only change the text color, to change the color of the div, use `background-color` instead. ***You will not see your color if your div does not have any content unless you give it a `width`/`height`***

here is an example:(*I used exaclty your code*)

```css
.header{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left:auto;
  width:100%; 
  background-color:#C60;
  height:60px; 
  overflow:hidden
}    

.logo1 { 
  color : #0F0; /**this will only change the text color**/
  overflow : auto 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" >
  <div class="header"> 
     <div class="logo1">Logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simply click *"Run code snippet"*

Comment: I've already put that in the comment, it seems that this is not the answer